# Running FlexUnit unable to get console output for trace

Tags: apache-flex, ant, flexunit

I've set up FlexUnit in my app, I want to debug a test using trace, but im not sure how to get flexunit to traceto the flashlog file.  Here's part of my test task in ant, I thought the 'localtrusted' property would help, but it doesnt seem to.  In my logs I get the testcases only, none of my traces which are inside my tests.

```
<flexunit
        workingDir="${test-output.dir}"
        toDir="${test-output.module.dir}/output"
        verbose="true"
        localtrusted="true"
        haltonfailure="false">
         <source dir="${basedir}/src" />
         <source dir="${basedir}/test-src" />
        <testSource dir="${basedir}/test-src">
            <include name="**/*Test*.as" />
        </testSource>
        <library dir="${env.CLI_ROOT}/tools" />
    </flexunit>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [DConsole](http://code.google.com/p/doomsdayconsole/) in your library path and it will output to the console if you use `debug/info/warn/error/fatal()` instead of `trace()`.

```
import com.furusystems.logging.slf4as.global.debug
debug("traces!");
```